# What should be done about answer 5479 to Shape and size of beard in Islam?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, copy-paste

[This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/5479/3487) answer to [Shape and size of beard in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5395/3487) has a huge chunk of [copy-paste](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/3487) content in it. The original text that it contains which attempts to answer the question is in the *"Shia"* section. Putting the copy-pastes aside it doesn't answer the question either.

What should be done about it?

Comment: The answer is currently deleted for not fitting our current policies.