# Is an explicitly attributed answer plagarism?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/was-it-ever-illegal-to-translate-the-quran-from-arabic) question about the legality of Islamic translation and tagged it *translations* and *quran*; and the moderator flagged it as better suited for the History site as its political/historical.

I cross-posted the question to the History site; it got an answer which I cross-posted back and explicitly attributed; the moderator says that it violates their cross-posting and plagarism policy  and shut the question down.

First I don't see it as counting as plagarism; essentially I'm *quoting* as I'm attributing to where it came from and who wrote it.

At worst - one can say that the answer should just have been linked; or I should have asked to have the question migrated originally; so the question of cross-linking an answer back doesn't arise.

But one rather gets the feeling that this site is not academically orientated - though it explicitly says that is in its site-help:" and those interested in Islam on an academic level." Doesn't Islam include its history, and its theology? Perhaps that description should be modified if this is not the case?

Answer (score 3):

Cross-(or Multi-)posting the question is [frowned upon](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) in general. Occasionally people will ask related questions on several sites to good results, but it's vital that each question is tailored to the site it's posted on. An example of this working well is this pair of questions:

- [Did Jephthah have pets?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/451/68)
- [What else could have come out of Yiftach's house?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11035/971)

Or this related pair:

- [Did Jephthah sacrifice his daughter?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2957/914)
- [Did Jephthah actually sacrifice his daughter?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1227/68)

Note that each question was specifically tailored to the sort of experts that populate each of the sites and that each question was answered differently. A person reading all four questions and their answers would have a pretty full understanding of a tricky bit of Hebrew scripture. This is shows off the strength of individual vertical question stacks.

But your [question on history](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/14139/690) was word-for-word identical to the question you asked here. And your answer was a word-for-word quotation of the answer you got there. On an ordinary site, that would be highly irregular. On a site that has a long battle against answers lifted wholesale from other sites... well, I can't think of a nice way to phrase my reaction.

Since you got a nice answer on the History site, I suggest deleting the question. Alternatively, [edit](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/14451/edit) it to address the Islam community of experts.

Comment: http://history.stackexchange.com/q/14190 http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14580

Answer (score 2):

> I cross-posted the question to the History site; it got an answer which I cross-posted back

If you were convinced with the answer there and found it to in fact be answering the verbatim question here then you should have deleted the question altogether. No point in keeping it around.

> the moderator says that it violates their cross-posting

It's the SE [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) which all the sites under its umbrella should adhere to. Not solely this site's policy.

> [violates] plagarism policy

the answer was not deleted for plagiarism it was deleted because it didn't adhere to the site's [**copy-paste policy**](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/953). As is stated in the [comment](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/was-it-ever-illegal-to-translate-the-quran-from-arabic#comment26718_14478) under it.

> [violates] shut the question down

that question is still open. I personally don't think it has anything to do with Islam. The only important thing that is in common, in that question and Islam is Quran. Based on the current, not so ironed out site policies on such history questions that question is kept open.

> I should have asked to have the question migrated originally

Exactly. Had you flagged the question for migration it could have been put up for it. Even if one didn't do it and actually cross-posted, they could come back and delete the question. Cross-posting both the question and answer is not doing any benefit in term of increasing the internet's signal-to-noise ratio and the site's health.

Comment: The copy-paste policy mentions plagarism as a key motivation; but never mind.