# Should question 18722 really be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

It was my question:

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18722/what-is-the-importance-of-the-unity-between-muslims-according-to-shia-traditio

I wrote a question regarding the importance of the unity between Muslims. I mentioned a verse of Quran and also a view of a Shia scholar (about it). Then I inquired if there is any relevant Hadith regarding its importance (from Shia).

So, a moderator put it on hold …

Was it really a broad question? And wasn't it really a good question for this site?

Comment: I edited your question for better coherence. This will hopefully help users understand your concern correctly and cast reopen votes.

Comment: Oh, @infatuated, Well done. you edited it relatively great. Perhaps this is now easier for users to figure it out .. God bless you.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking two different questions. That alone makes it too broad. Worse,  one of your questions is ill-defined; does Shia have a ranking system that would allow one to gauge the importance of individual verses? Are there verses that are commonly understood to be *unimportant*?! I don't think you asked what you intended to ask.

Focus on the problem that led you to ask this question. What concern are you hoping to address by learning more about this verse? Do you hope that it can be ignored? Do you hope it **cannot** be? Why?

Figure it out. Then ask the question you intended to.

Comment: Could you please explain what part of the question is vague for you?

Comment: Dear Mohammad Hossein, you are right. To be honest, I don't understand how it could be vague! I assume this is a clear question. Anyhow, @Shog9, my question has been edited to some extent. So, I recommend you to read it again (perhaps its  new edition would be more helpful for you). Good luck

Answer (score 2):

To me, the OP has came across a verse in Quran suggesting unity. Besides he see a Shi'a scholar emphasizing on the unity. Now, he would like to understand if there is any hadith among shia traditions regarding this issue. In fact, he would like to know if he has understand that verse correctly and why some of the Shi'a scholars seek unity between Muslims.

It is clear enough to me.

Comment: You have figured out my question relatively good. Actually I wanna know regarding the reasons of its importance. (and also regarding relevant Hadiths (of Shia)..   Good luck.

Comment: The question was never closed for being unclear.  It was closed for being too broad and for being a poor fit for this site, and this post does nothing to address either of those issues.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained when I closed it, the question as worded "just encourages cherry-picking and lists of items".  Even with the current edits and clarifications, I see nothing that looks to have actually addressed this issue.

[Real questions have *answers*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), not lists of items.  No matter how I read it, you don't look to be [asking a "real" question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145677/132874): You're basically just expressing an opinion, and asking for…well…pretty much anything that agrees with it.

I know I've directed you to the advice in our [help centre](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) before, but it bears repeating here.  In particular, I would like to point out the following from the page on "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)":

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

The question as written is entirely subjective, and fails to meet most of [Robert's criteria for a good subjective question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).    What makes, for example, the extant answer (with three upvotes) — an answer which simply quotes one *ayah* and one *hadith* while providing [zero original content](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/22) — in any way better or worse than any other answer?

Your question gives absolutely no criteria for judging the answers, which just throws the entire voting process to the whims of opinion rather than usefulness.  All I see it accomplishing is encouraging the sort of [echo chamber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_%28media%29) effect that already plagues Islamic forums, which does little to encourage any actual *academic* study of Islam.

That is not the sort of question the Stack Exchange model is geared to handle.