# Deleted answer on question "does changing clothes breaks wudu?"

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

Qestion here: [does changing clothes breaks wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10105/does-changing-clothes-breaks-wudu/)

My answer was:

> No, these are not causes of invalidation.
>
> Reasons of [invalidation are:](http://www.questionsonislam.com/article/what-are-things-invalidate-and-break-wudu)
>
> 1 – Any najasah, liquid or solid matter coming out of the penis and
>   anus like urine, feces, sperm, madi, blood, etc.
>
> 2 – Breaking wind from the anus (farting).
>
> 3 – Blood, pus, yellow liquid, etc flowing from any part of the body
>   * According to Shafiis, leakage of blood, pus, yellow liquid that does not come from the genital organs and anus does not invalidate wudu.
>
> 4 – To vomit mouthful.
>
> 5 – If blood equaling to saliva or more than saliva comes out of the
>   mouth, wudu is invalidated.
>
> 6 – Sleeping, which makes a person lose control over himself,
>   invalidates wudu
>
> 7– To faint for a short or long time.
>
> 8 – To laugh **during the prayer**. Smiling and laughing are two
>   different things. When someone laughs, it is heard by others.
>   Therefore, it invalidates wudu if someone laughs while praying. When
>   wudu is invalidated, the prayer is invalidated, too. Smiling does not
>   invalidate the prayer or wudu since it is silent. However, if a person
>   laughs so silently and if he himself hears it only, his prayer is
>   invalidated but his wudu is not. 
>   * According to Shafiis, even the laughter in the prayer does not invalidate wudu.
>
> 9 – Sexual intercourse or extreme touching. According to Hanafis, if
>   the skins of a man and a woman touches each other, their wudus are not
>   invalidated; however, if a woman and a man touches each other while
>   they are naked or if they touch each other with lust without a garment
>   that will prevent them from feeling the heat of their bodies, or if
>   they caress and hug each other like that, their wudus are invalidated.
>   According to Shafiis, wudu is invalidated when the skin of a woman and
>   a man touches each other. According to Malikis and Hanbalis, wudu is
>   invalidated if sexual pleasure is felt when the skins touch each
>   other.
>
> 10 – If a person who has made tayammum sees water, his wudu is
>   invalidated.
>
> 11 – When the time for a prayer ends, wudu of an excused person is
>   invalidated.
>
> 12 – Getting drunk by taking alcohol or drugs invalidates wudu. It is
>   definitely haram to take intoxicating drinks but the amount that does
>   not make a person drunk does not invalidate wudu.

And comments:

> Nice brief answer. It can be nicer if you add the reasons of invalidation (directly) in your good answer. Good luck dear mate. –
>   DearMartyr Sheikh Nimr-Al-Nimr Jan 17 at 16:09
>              Thanks, I added the reasons of invalidation – nim Jan 18 at 8:40
>              Well done buddy. – DearMartyr Sheikh Nimr-Al-Nimr Jan 19 at 11:47
>
> We require that answers consist [primarily of the words of their author](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/953/the-copy-paste-issue-r%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bevisited), and that [all quotes be clearly marked as such and attributed to their respective authors](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If you can abide by these rules, you may
>   post a new answer here. – goldPseudo♦ yesterday

As far as I see deletion was fair on first sight. But then I thought only problem was maybe not giving authors name on quote. It can be corrected by only editing. Deleting answer was so harsh. I added new answer as original answer of mine at first hand. I didn't add quoted text and as you can see at comments, one of our fellow friend ask me to add quotes there then I added.
My answer to question was simple like "No, these are not causes of invalidation." These part was useful and it was enough to answer
Today i just see [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/516703/2807313) and I thought it's same like my answer. Why do we have different rule sor each SE site? Or our moderation takes harsh decision that not fit with SE community?

I am simply asking this question to understand rules of Islam SE. If these way accepted as being different from other SE sites, I can live with that. I want to clarify my mind on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

There are several differences to be noted between the SO answer you link and yours. One is that it calls out the source of the material. Another is that it answers the question even if you remove the cited material. It uses the citation to strengthen and elaborate on the answer, not *be* the answer. Without the (unreferenced) citation material in your answer the post would not really answer the question at all. As the comment says, answers are required to answer the question in their own words even if they also have citations. Citations are a good thing, they just are not a substitute for original content.

The SE sites share some common themes, but yes each site does typically also have its own set of rules. This particular rule is not unique to Islam.SE either, most (maybe all, I'm just not familiar with one) of the other religion sites enforce something very similar. A few sites are even much stricter.