# What are the rules on editing questions into completely new questions, for Islam SE and SE in general?

Tags: discussion, questions

This [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39866/) has multiple revisions. Initially 
in [revision 1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/39866/1), the question was about the steps a muslim ruler has to take before declaring jihad. It was revised later in [revision 5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/39866/5) to be about references to mubahala between Moses and Qaroon. Finally, in [revision 7 then 8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/39866/7) about caliphs taking Jizyah from polytheists.

One of the deleted answers (due to the answer being a complete copy-and-paste) is addressing the question in revision 5. Had the answer not been deleted, it would have appeared to be completely irrelevant to the question.

Is this behavior of editing questions in entirety allowed by Islam SE? I doubt it, but I could not find anything to govern this on Islam Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it is not acceptable (see relevant MSE question at [Should I use existing questions to "ask new ones" when in a question ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261673/132874)). If there has been pretty much *any* significant activity on the previous question (comments, answers, votes), changing the question just renders all that previous activity obsolete and, in the case of votes, arguably straight-up fraud (any positive votes would *NOT* have been for the new question, giving it an unfair advantage over having been posted anew).

Right now, taking action on that question would be counterproductive, since it currently *has* significant activity taken on it due to the current form (and had not had significant activity in the previous form): The copy-pasted answer had already been deleted before the question was changed (and [wouldn't be welcome on the site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/22) anyway), and the only votes cast on it were for the question it's asking *now*. Deleting it or rolling it back now would also render Medi1Saif's efforts in [*his* answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/41084/22) completely irrelevant, effectively wasting his time and hurting his reputation unnecessarily.

However, this should be considered an exception; if the post had had even one upvote or one viable answer from its earlier form(s) I would've rolled it back instantly, new answers or no. Encouraging this sort of behaviour risks well-intentioned contributions getting wiped out during cleanup (moreso than answering poorly-written or unclear questions in general), which is just not fair to the people volunteering their time to help. If you do see this sort of thing in the future, don't hesitate to roll it back and warn the poster *before* other users see it and unwittingly contribute to the wrong post.

Comment: Ups sorry I didn't realize that that was the question, with the many radical changes!

Comment: hah there's a fair chance that I'd get a 3rd up-vote and can get the disciplined badge as the whole thing about this question and questioner seems to be absurd!

Comment: Now I deleted my answer!