# Is re-phrasing/changing my so far unanswered question ok?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

I have a question due to the discussion of  [What are the rules on editing questions into completely new questions, for Islam SE and SE in general?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/what-are-the-rules-on-editing-questions-into-completely-new-questions-for-islam)

As I'm really thinking of completely re-phrasing my question [What is the view of Islam on a child of a haram relationship?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43841/what-is-the-view-of-islam-on-a-child-of-a-haram-relationship) to make it sound more like what Islam offers to protect children of zina from any kind of abuse or mistreating related to their parents sins?

So my question would it be ok to do so? I mean it is possible that some my take it as precedent to do so in future? So maybe my question is: would this change be of a kind as mentioned in the linked meta post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the proposed change to your question is acceptable. Typically, a question would have four aspects:

1. Concept: the main topic of the question, which is advisable to be one per question.
2. Context: all related conditions, limitations, exemptions, etc., that may be affected by people involved, place, time, etc. Typically, such attributes would affect the tags.
3. Accessibility: being on topic, answerable, not a duplicate, etc.
4. Presentation: language, spelling, formatting, etc., which is made available for the OP and those with edit privileges (requiring or not requiring approval) through the edit capability.

In my opinion, edits should be done on any item on the list without significantly affecting the item above. Hence:

- An overall topic change is not allowed.
- A context change should be limited to the OP, and done with caution, long as it does not alter the topic.
- A change to a question's accessibility by editing is encouraged when needed to make the question more applicable to ISE but without affecting the topic or the context.

So, I would say the edits you are recommending are OK. I realize that "measuring" the attributes of a question is not an easy task as such, so the above is a guideline more than anything else.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit my question then, I think I waited long enough for some different opinion!