# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, deleted-answer

My answer to [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17413/if-a-person-does-good-deeds-throughout-his-life-but-never-believed-in-god-will/17443?noredirect=1#comment32080_17443) was deleted because a moderator came to the wrong conclusion that I plagiarized the answer. It was not anywhere near plagiarism. How can I get my answer reinstated?

Comment: Why would someone heavily down vote a question clarification?

Comment: @muslim1 I can't speak for everyone who downvoted, but I imagine it's because as phrased it's really not much of a "question clarification".  The question is clearly taking a "This action taken against me was wrong" stance, but provides pretty much zero in the way of actually *arguing* that point.  Multiple people obviously felt that either (a) showed insufficient research effort (b) was unclear or (c) was not useful.  Ergo, downvotes.

Comment: @goldPseudo I think he disagrees with plagiarism. That's why he asked the question. As you have answered it showing pilgrims, that is the right way to handle it. Not simply downovting it.

Answer (score 5):

Please [submit a new answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/take-pride-in-your-community-and-work-to-build-a-site-you-can-be-proud-of) and be sure to:

1. Show copied material using block quotes:

   ```
   > Allah does not task any soul beyond its capacity.
   ```
2. Cite each source of copied material. Use a link if possible:

   ```
   [Quran 2:286](http://islamawakened.com/quran/2/286/)
   ```
3. Cite any sources of ideas:

   ```
   As noted by Ali Quli Qara'i...
   ```
4. If the bulk of an answer comes from elsewhere, use your own words to customize it for the question asked *on this site*.

Comment: I'm sure that I followed all these rule so I believe that it is the moderator's decision that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The answer was deleted for plagiarism because on investigation, it clearly appeared to be derived from a third-party source without attribution.  For the purposes of this analysis, I have taken samples from section 3 in [your answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/17443/2) (as current at the time of deletion), and used for comparison the text of [an article found at Al-Islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/faith-and-reason-ayatullah-mahdi-hadavi-tehrani/question-13-non-muslims-and-hell) (which may or may not be the original source, given that [a cursory Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22Those+who+do+not+believe+in+Islam+can+be+classified+into+two+groups%3A%22&oq=%22Those+who+do+not+believe+in+Islam+can+be+classified+into+two+groups%3A%22) indicates no shortage of sites where it can be found verbatim as a copy-paste).

<sup>(all screenshots courtesy of [Copyscape's webpage text comparer thingy](http://www.copyscape.com/compare.php), all freehand red annotations courtesy of me and caffeine)</sup>

[image: Section 3.1 analysis]

In this and all other screenshots, text from the answer posted to this site is on the left, and the article of comparison on the right. Even a cursory analysis shows significant similarities between the two, from the transliteration style and literal translation used for "Jahil-e-Muqassir", the particular words chosen to make particular points, and especially the *order* those points (and words) were *made*.

Even the text that *wasn't* calculated in the 26% match still matches the original so closely that coincidence is unlikely.  In many cases, it looks like words were simply cut out and/or replaced with synonyms to make it not a *direct* copy-paste, but that doesn't make it in any way not *plagiarism*.

[image: Section 3.2 analysis]

The second section is worse, mostly due to the 16-word sample that is *verbatim* the same as the original article.  This one also includes the suspicious use of "real" quotes `‘’` (which almost inevitably comes from text copied *directly* from web-pages).

And your conclusion, arguing about spiritual regression of mankind and the world-dominating propaganda machine which distorts the truth, also maps way too closely to the same arguments made in the original article.

Even if your answer does contain some original content, there are *far* too many coincidences between the two articles to judge it as anything *but* [plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism): You have taken the ideas and arguments (and often the exact *words*) of someone else and presented them as if they were your own.

[So I deleted it.](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/22)

Comment: Caffeine surely does wonders ;)

Answer (score -1):

**1**.**I wrote at least 460 words** in my first answer **40 of which** (let's assume that goldPseudo was accurate) were the same as the source I extracted my answer from:

1. By doing a quick calculation you'll find out that **as few as 8.6%** of my answer matched the source.
2. I modified my answer again so that it would meet all the standards. This time the number of the words matching the source **decreased to 25 words out of at least 460 words** which means that just **5.4%** of the answer were the same as my source.

(let's ignore that the moderator believe that the letter **"e"** is called **"one** **word"**!!! Do you really see as many as 3 words here?!! **Jahil-e-Muqassir**.)

**2**.I didn't presented my answer as it were my own. I did not thick it would be necessary to provide the readers with sources so I have no problem with mentioning my source at the end of my answer if they stop deleting my answers.

Comment: By my examination, your modified text is still plagiarism.  All you did was swap out a few more synonyms and insert a bit more text, but did *absolutely nothing* about the fact that it is fundamentally *somebody else's work*.

Comment: poor examination!

Comment: How about owning up to the fact that you were adapting source material that was not yours. If you properly credited that in the first place this wouldn't be an issue. There's nothing wrong with doing that but it _has to be_ delineated and properly cited or it in plagiarism (no matter how many words you swap out).

Comment: let's put an end to playing with words. A fair person never hesitate that my answer did not violate the rule. It it crystal clear that although the whole answer was extracted from a source, I managed to spell it out using my own sentences, examples and words without breaking any rule. 2+2 = 4 whether you say two plus two equals 4, makes 4 or whatever you'd like to put it. The result is always the same!

Comment: [Your comment](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/why-was-my-answer-deleted#comment4841_1375) only goes to prove our point: by your own admission here on meta you extracted the basic elements of the answer from another source. **So credit the source!** What's so hard about that?