# My answer to the Question Number 24176 is deleted. what's your opinion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

**This is the** **[Question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24176/what-to-do-with-the-riba-interest-money)**:

I have some interest money in my account and I recently came to know it is haram. I want to get rid of it. Please tell me the ways to spend it.

Can I spend it as wedding or birthday gift to my reletives? Can I give it to my mother or sister?

**And here is my answer:**

When Halal properties get mixed up with Haram properties in a way that you cannot differentiate between them, you have to pay Khums (one fifth of the whole properties) to those who are entitled of receiving Khums so that you will get rid of Haram part but there are THREE CONDITIONS:

1. The owner of Haram part is not known.
2. The quantity of Haram part is not known.
3. It is not known whether the quantitiy of Haram part is more or less than Khums (One fifth of the whole properties)

If the first condition is missed i.e you know the owner of Haram part but the quantity of it is unknown, you should come to an agreement with the owner and make sure that all of the owner's properties are paid off.

If the second condition is missed i.e you know the quantity of Haram part without knowing the owner - regardless of it being less or more than Khums of the whole properties- you should give that amount as Sadaqeh (charity) on behalf of the owner With the permission of Mujtahid.

**And this is the comment of the [Moderator](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/22/goldpseudo) who has deleted my answer:**

*This does absolutely nothing to answer the question!*

Does it make sense to you? I believe that the Moderator has not understood the Question.

Answer (score 1):

The question is clearly tagged [hanafi](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hanafi).  Unless Ayatollah Sistani has become an authority in Hanafi jurisprudence while I wasn't looking, I don't see how your answer is remotely relevant.

Assuming for a minute that he is in fact a Hanafi authority, the majority of your answer is explaining about a situation where, and I quote, "Halal properties get mixed up with Haram properties in a way that you cannot differentiate between them," whereas the questioner is clear that the money she's asking about is *explicitly* haram; she doesn't mention anything about it being mixed or undifferentiable.

The only part of the answer that is directly relevant to the *actual* question asked is the last half of the last paragraph:

> …you should give that amount as Sadaqeh (charity) on behalf of the owner With the permission of Mujtahid.

Which is....vague; it's definitely lacking enough meat to warrant an actual *answer*.  The questioner is explicitly asking for the ways in which she can spend this money, and you basically just lumped that into "sadaqeh (charity)" without even an attempt at elaboration.

So, yeah, not an answer.

---

On further examination, it's also clearly plagiarised from the first three answers found at http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2289/:
[image]
 <sup>--- Screencap taken from http://www.copyscape.com/compare.php</sup>

[Plagiarism is not acceptable here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) (a fact which [has been made clear to you before](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1370/22)).  Even aside from the plagiarism issue, we as a site expect answers to show *actual expertise*; given how shallow your own edits were to the third party text (cosmetic, at best), and how poorly they pertain to the *actual question asked*, all you've done is demonstrate that you really shouldn't even be *trying* to answer this question.

We as a site expect that "[answers consist primarily of the words of their author](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1157/22)" 
If the best you can do is [poorly paraphrase other people's work](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/22), this is not the site for you.

Comment: You still have difficulty understanding the Question!!

Comment: @Amin He explained pretty clearly that 1) your source wasn't hanafi (which is what the question asked for), 2) your answer isn't talking about properties that are entirely haram (as the question had), and 3) your answer is plagiarized. Any of those alone would disqualify it as an answer. Where _specifically_ did his explanation go wrong? It's easy to say "you didn't understand the question" but since I find his explanation perfectly clear and I find your problem with it entirely unclear, perhaps it is you who have misunderstood?

Comment: Just a small request, could you explain a little as to how do you track down the source from the answer? Very damn curious to know.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser It's more art than science.  Mostly I just pick out particular turns of phrase or vocabulary and google them.  It's easier to do the more familiar I am with (a) the poster's own writing style or (b) particular scholar's writing styles, but scholars and laymen tend to write *very* differently, and with experience those differences can be pretty obvious.

Comment: i think asking only for hanafi and deleting other asnwers is not needed for all users of this site, because, muslims should be united/unite, as i know from qur'an, so please do not additionally and artificilaly divide us.

Comment: @qdinar This has already been discussed here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/562/22. In short, we are a Q&A site for focussed answers to focussed questions; when someone asks a *particular* question, and wants a *particular* answer (i.e. according to Hanafi jurisprudence), it is *in no way useful* to him to clutter his thread with answers he *explicitly does not want*.

Comment: i think tags are not well visible and cannot be clearly understood as exlusive asking for a mazhab, so such questions should be edited.

Comment: @qdinar Then go and suggest the edit.