# What is a clear result of "delete on sight policy for plagiarism" *proposal*?

Tags: discussion

The meta question: [delete on sight" policy for plagiarism](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/369/22) is a proposal and it is not a rule of site.

It has many different answers. but I could not understand a clear official result from it.

The selected answers says it is not about new uses. right?

What is a clear official result of this long QA?

Has any extracted result from this QA added to help center as an official rule?

In [some answers](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/403/67) it says this rule is different about new users and established users.

> For users who have been around for a while, and who have accumulated a
>   lot of reputation, we're going to be a lot more strict about this.
>   You're expected to know "by now" because you've been such an active
>   participant in the system, how to do things right.

Please note the proposal itself is clear. but the result is not clear. i.e. if this proposal is accepted or rejected? and if accepted with or without any change? what is the button line outcoe of this long discussion?

The accepted answer by asker is the result? or the answer with most up vote? or other model? I do not understand how a result is concluded from a meta QA with different answers.

Comment: @Downvoters could you please explain the reason for the downvote? This question is in fact asking something which I haven't seen addressed anywhere. What I think it's basically questioning is that how is a de-facto  community policy establish?

Comment: I obviously can't speak for everyone who downvoted, but I simply don't see what was unclear about the post to begin with.  And the question on whether it's been added to the help center as an official rule is trivial to answer simply [by reading it](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as there is only one site-editable page in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

What's not clear?  The proposal was to implement the following policy, which I quote verbatim:

---

> In terms of improperly-cited cut-paste answers, please note that going
> forward, **these answers will be deleted without warning.**
>
> Some of you frequently indulge in this practice. So far, we've been
> polite enough to point it out and request you to update your answers,
> without much (perhaps only a DV in some cases). This has now changed.
> Please flag plagiarized answers so we can address them promptly.
>
> Of course, you are **welcome to edit the answer so it is properly cited.**
> This is essentially what we want you to do.
>
> Properly citing and formatting a quote must include, at minimum, a mention of where the text was copied from (regardless of it is from an online or an offline source), with large blocks of quoted text formatted in a distinct blockquote (i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> in the editing window).
>
> This will help the site overall with quality, and will also keep it
> from wandering into potentially dangerous legal grounds.

---

The accepted answer says that this policy was implemented.

As far as I'm concerned, adding it to the help center is wholly unnecessary; the meta post on "[What to do about plagiarism?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/22)" is already under [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), which also states that plagiarised posts will be deleted without warning.

The FAQ post predated not only the policy proposal, but also the moderator pro-tem appointments; plagiarised posts were already being deleted on sight by the Stack Exchange community team before this site even had it's own *moderators*.  All we did was formalize it.

Comment: the process that this proposal is accepted for site or not and how is unclear. why the accepted answer by asker should be as the rule of site? why not the answer with most up vote? why this model? in this case any one can ask a question and choose a best answer and so it becomes a rule? also the accepted answer is different about new and established users. but do mods treat new users different?