# Quran and Sunnah as basis for Answer

Tags: discussion

Considerable amount of the answers I see which doesn't Quote Quran or Hadith as a reference (don't want to point to any particular question here), I would like to suggest/get feedback on mentioning/enforcing "no direct reference in Quran or Hadith" in answers. I agree that some times we need to inference the answer from something else. But it should not be the first thing to do.

> [Quran 4:59](https://quran.com/4/59) if you disagree over anything, refer it to Allah and the Messenger

As a matter of fact, I believe It is better to mention in every answer that "There is no direct reference for so and so in Quran or Authentic Hadith" (if it is actually the case) as the first point before the actual answer.

As Prophet Mohammed (SAL) said in the Last Sermon

> O People, no prophet or apostle will come after me, and no new faith
>   will be born.  Reason well, therefore, O people, and understand words
>   which I convey to you.  **I leave behind me two things, the Quran and my
>   example, the Sunnah, and if you follow these you will never go astray.**

I believe these statements are inline with the Objectives of ISLAM.SE

Comment: Well try to use them correctly in your posts and be a good example for others!

Comment: @Sassir Definitely Brother. I am new to this kind of forum. so still, I am learning how to answer under different circumstances. Yes, I am looking back to my answers and correcting as necessary with references. 

One more request to the moderators is that, give an opportunity to newbies like me to correct our answers before downvoting.

Comment: ISE is a community moderated Q&A site not a typical internet forum, it is your duty to do your best in giving a good answer, and up-voting good answers and good questions, down-votes should only show that there's something wrong with the content of a post,,, we have basically 3 mods here (diamond users) only one of them is very active. But lately the community has become more active than ever since I've been here, so don't blame mods and don't care about down-votes if you think you did your best, that just happens to any of us, even if some are judging posters etc. and that can be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please vote accordingly---this is the usual quality control mechanism.  Seeing answers which quote the Qur'an and/or Sunnah being upvoted will encourage users to write other such posts, and help them rise to the top (like in the [tour page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour)).

The other thing that can help is commenting on answers to highlight the problem with lack of references.

---

I don't think we should be enforcing anything here.  Different people have different opinions as to what a good-quality answer entails.  The usual stance I've experienced at StackExchange is that if it answers the question, it stays (although we also delete [copy/paste](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/324/17163) and [plagiarised](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/17163) answers), and voting gives a rough guide to its quality.

(And welcome to Islam.SE!)