# Where I can see the list of deleted posts by moderators?

Tags: support

As one of moderators said:

> There's no reason it should be the moderator's responsibility to
>   personally edit a poorly-attributed post, considering there's
>   thousands of other users who can edit or suggest exactly the same
>   thing.

Some of them have been deleted for not having a small edit. specifically those who are deleted on sight for not having a proper quotation mark.

So I want to see and improve some of them to can be undeleted.

Also I do not want to check the pages one by one to find such deleted posts.

So is there anywhere that show the list of deleted posts by moderators?

Answer (score 4):

We have had a long-standing request to [show your own deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/1438), which has been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). However, a few concessions have been made to help users view their own deleted content:

1. If you have a link to the post, you can see it even after deletion.
2. There are links to show your posts that have been deleted in the last 90 days.

Once you reach the [access to moderator tools](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (2k on betas, 10k on graduated sites), you'll be able to see all deleted answers *in situ*. You'll also be able to view deleted questions if you have the link. One place to find such posts in the [Recently Deleted](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days) section of the moderator tools.

---

I applaud your desire to salvage posts that need editing in order to be welcome on this site. Certainly if there are some great answers that just needed a bit in the way of fixing formatting or minor grammar, you'd be doing a great service. But **the time to correct these problems is before deletion**. When you notice great answers that has problems, use your [edit privilege](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to fix them.

I should also note that I looked at a sample of recent deletions and I personally can't imagine how most of them could be fixed. There are a lot of answers that are literal copies of material found elsewhere. Removing them before this site aquires a reputation as a [content farm](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/302/138) is the best course of action. The onus is largely on the author of the post to provide original content in answers.

Comment: Recently Deleted shows only 3 recent items. is there any way to see more than 3 items? still there are deleted posts that can be improved. for example those having both original content and copied content that are deleted on sight for plagiarism or other issues before I see the post for first time.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala, click on the triangle to expand the list.

Comment: @Kaveh yes I clink and it shows only 3 last item. without clicking on it nothing is showed.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala, first click on 30d on the top, that will refresh the page, then click on the triangle. When I do I see a very long list of recently deleted questions.