# Why my answer to question 934 is deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer, delete-reason

I saw my [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/934/why-shia-muslims-use-a-stone-for-saying-prayers-but-sunni-muslims-dont/938#938) to the question *[Why Shia Muslims use a stone for saying prayers but Sunni Muslims don't?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/934/3487)* is deleted. I tried to understand why it is deleted. I edited it different times and removed parts of it. also I resolved some plagiarism issues in it and then flagged it for undelete. but the result of flag says:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

And still it is deleted still when its problems are resolved. I do not understand why it is deleted. it has a list of Sunni and Shia hadith to prove why shia use stone for prayer. but I do not think having a list of hadith be illegal in this site.

Comment: Details can be found here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14815883#14815883

Comment: why no moderator feels responsibility to answer this question?

Comment: Because no one is responsible to answer the question.

Comment: @BleedingFingers I tried to understand the reason of delete and found some reason and resolved them and flagged it but it is still deleted. so how can I understand what is the current reason of being deleted? I feel shia users are treated as second class citizen. for deleting mods are active but for saying reason they are lazy.

Comment: I don't agree with the second last statement. I'll look into the post, now that I can, and see if all the addressed problem are resolved and it could be undeleted. In spare time.

Comment: @BleedingFingers thanks for your effort. if you saw it can be undeleted then what will happen? another user below said it can be undeleted. but it seems mods ignored it. do you think your opinion will not be ignored again? I do not know how is the process of decision making in meta QAs. it is not clear. this site looks like a one man company.

Comment: @BleedingFingers that question is not asking for shia evidence. it asks "why". also a shia evidence does not mean a hadith narrated by a shia narrator only. a shia evidence can be a sunni hadith if its narrators are reliable. http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1075/67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link to chatroom by BleedingFingers above, it seems that your answer was pointed out for plagiarism by another user, the moderator agreed and deleted your answer which had +26 votes.

The judgement seems a bit unfair to me. It does have a lot of text from your own and have references to some of the hadith. The moderator seems to be discussing Sunni and Shia hadiths in the comments which I think he should not. We shouldn't bring Sunni and Shia while moderating. We should look at the content and decide if it violates the SO policies are not.

I suggest, please provide references to at least a couple of hadith at the bottom. I think the answer should be undeleted. If you cannot find a quoted hadith, please explain at the bottom, why reference to a hadith cannot be found.

Comment: the answer was edited and plagiarism was resolved and ahadith have their references. but after flagging it, was not undeleted.

Comment: The judgment was fair and square. The content was plagiarized and had to be taken down.

Answer (score -1):

**The why?**

Reason why it is deleted is because the post is in clear violation of the plagiarism policy of this site as is discussed in [What to do about plagiarism?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/3487).

[This](http://al-rida.net/index.php/islam/faqs/prayer-faq/9-Prayer/9-why%20Shia%20prostrate%20on%20Mud) is the source of the content which was copy/pasted.

Even is the source of the content was stated and everything blockquoted the post would still be in violation of the community policy regarding [copy/paste](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/3487) answers.

**The resolution:**

1. Everything in between *"Abu Said Al Khudri narrates:"* (inclusive) and *"one shia Hadith:* (exclusive) be removed. Why I see it's the offshoot of plagiarized content and should be there.
2. It should answer the question. i.e. *"Why such difference in style?"* because the question isn't asking *"Why the style?"*

Although, I suggest the deletion be reversed when the pointer number one is met. And from there on let the votes decide and right now all the votes on that answer are unlocked and voter can reassess there decision *judiciously*.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. I don't really see plagiarism in the said question (or it has already been removed). What you said should be removed are quoted hadiths, is that really plagiarism? In what form please?

Are we taking plagiarism *too* seriously particularly against Shia members?

Comment: The content is pretty mixed up now. And the current content in the region demarcated above is a result of a series of edits made on top of plagiarized material. But you can still find the exact stuff which leads to the the source (e.g. the *"Hazrat Maimuna said:"* and *"Jabir bin Abdullah narrates:"* part). Like I said that region would be better off deleted or else the answer is. The pattern in which the hadith are quoted is plagiarized its not original content. Even the source of the cited hadith don't match word by word.

Comment: I, personally, try my level best to judge the answer not the author. Policy are to be taken too seriously and author's membership in X shouldn't have any bearing on that. Where X could be belief, race, color status, class, position, SE rep and badges etc.

Comment: I think this approach of stricly following the policy is totally ridiculous. This answer got +20 up votes. It has quote haidths. It has statements from his own. Who are *we* to delete answer based on *strict criteria*. This site is own by public. Moderators should relax and step aside if they are not *clear enough*. Do not take it too seriously.

Comment: Please, find them and flag them appropriately. That would be great service you'll be doing to the site.

Comment: And like I said it *has* original content. And the only thing that I have suggested be removed is the demarcated region.

Comment: My point is, most the question deleted by moderators are not flagged at all. I don't have prove for it but I think they took personnel decisions on it.

Comment: Provide evidence to "not flagged at all". Even if you do, do you think that, that question didn't deserve a deletion? If so, bring it over to meta.

Comment: Being a regular user, I can't view or have access to that data. I have seen really stupid answers here which have stayed for months and months. But I have seen answers which are deleted right when they are posted. I am affirmative, moderators do take actions on their own! I am not against it, but I am worried they take action only against Shia people.

Comment: I wonder how your two meta post apply to my answer. only part of my answer is copied and it is cited. with reference. also it is not all copy paste. so your other meta post does not apply. please reconsider.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala Your references are incorrect. The original source of that region is the above mentioned page not the one you mentioned. The original content shall remain no problem with that. Plus like I said it doesn't answer the question "why the difference ..." but that's not the reason of deletion.

Comment: @BleedingFingers both your any [my reference](http://www.shia.org/aboutprayers.htm) have the same text. I have no problem changing it. do you think it has still any plagiarism problem? if answering or not the question is another issue.

Comment: Could you please clearly repeat what you said. I couldn't understand it properly.

Comment: @BleedingFingers you said I have copied from [this source](http://al-rida.net/index.php/islam/faqs/prayer-faq/9-Prayer/9-why%20Shia%20prostrate%20on%20Mud). but I have copied from another source with the same text and have mentioned it as reference. I do not think current version has any  plagiarism problem. are you sure it has?