# Why my answer to question 12848 is not undeleted?

Tags: discussion, moderators, plagiarism, deleted-answer, delete-reason

My answer to the following question (https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12848/did-yazid-order-his-soldiers-to-kill-imam-hussain) was deleted for plagiarism. I believed that this is not plagiarism and the existing similarities are not good reasons to accuse me (It was selected as the accepted answer). However, I edited the answer so that it become undeleted and I flagged the edited answer for being undeleted. Unfortunately, the flag was not helpful and the new edited answer was not undeleted.

[image: Did Yazid]

Could you please explain why my answer was not undeleted? I mean show me the exact parts which shows plagiarism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We take a [dim view of plagiarism](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/302/138) and it's been a continual problem here since the beginning. When a new answer rolls in and it's possible to find other sites that use phrases not in blockquotes, we empower and encourage moderators to just delete. The onus is on the author to show that their edit corrected the problem and not the other way around.

The two instances of using words from other sites that were mentioned in the comments *have* been fixed, so I undeleted the answer and made a couple of edits. I also purged the comment section.

In the future, please don't borrow content from other sites. Make your first revision a good answer for the site.