# Translation of key meta discussion

Tags: discussion

Let's face it. There is (pure guess, but wouldn't be far-fetched) and will be a large portion of users coming to this site in order to be a valuable part of the community but unfortunately won't be fluent in English reading and writing.

So it can be expected of them to act in a manner that is against the sites policies e.g. engaging in [plagiarism](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193) or [copy-pasting from external sources](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/953). No problem with that. The community would be happy to guide them to a relevant meta discussion so that they may learn the ropes. But not all user are able to get a (good) grasp of those discussion given their limited fluency in reading and writing in English. And this could lead to problems.

Based on that, I'm coining a proposal that whoever has command over any language other than English and wishes to volunteer, provide translations of the key policies of this site. This I suppose would be of great benefit and be helpful in channeling users not fluent in English to.

Does the community agree with the proposal? If not, then do you have an alternative proposal or any improvement to the above said?

And if so, then please suggest how should we carry it forward and how should it be done?

Comment: Great idea! This would also serve as a great opportunity for users to improve their Eng. fluency by reading meta discussions bilingually!

Comment: Good idea. I would assume Arabic and Urdu are most dominant languages our users speak after English. So, starting with those would be much useful I think.

Comment: If they can't read English, how are they going to contribute on the site? This is an English-language site. I don't see any point in translating all of the meta discussions into another language for the benefit of people who are not going to be able to contribute to the site anyway.

Comment: @Daniel I disagree. There are users who do know English but aren't able *get a (good) grasp of those discussion given their limited fluency in reading and writing in English.* But that doesn't mean they can't contribute by asking and answering. [If you struggle to write in English, just do your best and ask an editor to help you improve it.](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1157/3487). And I mentioned *key policies of this site* not all of the meta discussions.

Answer (score 1):

**I say we have it.**

The rules:

- create a language tag in which the policy is being being translated [arabic](/questions/tagged/arabic)
- all the discussions therein shall be in **read-only** mode ([read-only](/questions/tagged/read-only)?). i.e. all and any consensus reached therein shall have no effect on the site policies. Anything that is to have an affect on the site policies has to be discussed and presented in English.
- questions *about* the site could be asked in another language and be answered in the same language
- provide a link to the original discussion so that when user sent the original one they can find a link to the translated version in the "Linked" section on the right-side of the page

Comment: "questions about the site could be asked in another language and be answered in the same language". I don't think it is a good idea. SE staff should be able to understand and respond to meta discussions. I don't think SE has community managers that can speak Arabic/Urdu/Turkish/Persian etc.

Comment: SE has many sites (proposal) that are in other languages. I'm sure that include languages that nobody in the SE staff understands. Klingon was once [proposed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52617/klingon-language-usage) too ;).

Comment: As far as I know, SE sites in other languages are on hold until a community manager who speaks that language is hired. See: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/13340/47660

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100%, this would require users who have good command of the english language so that they can actually understand what is being said, I am not saying I have a good command, but I am willing to volunteer and help out.

As for how we should carry it forward, of course it starts by choosing a post/discussion the the following steps should happen:

1. After a discussion was chosen for translation, a new meta post/discussion should be started for the purpose of translating that meta post/discussion
2. Translation should be proposed through answers, and the best translation should be shown through voting

   - Use chat to discuss translations, what should be translated, what is good, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This means the user will know the rules but still won't be able to take a part in the community since he just doesn't know English(at least not to the point to be able to read the rules), well such a user won't benefit the site at all since he is not going to answer anything, **unless**

- There should be a way that a none English user could kinda write answers and someone translate or edit the answer
- Such users will need to understand English Q or A to act properly.

So I don't see a point here in translating the rules unless we find a way for the above matters,

BUT Still I think categorizing discussions and known rules into a single document is very necessary

Comment: [If you struggle to write in English, just do your best and ask an editor to help you improve it.](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1157/3487) There is a difference between not being able to read and write in English, and not being fluent enough to have a good grasp of site policies and discussions.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, uh OK!

Comment: @BleedingFingers but still, Bludream makes a really good point. If someone can't really understand such a post. I don't think he will be really comfortable participating in this site. His lack of understanding might cause more harm than benefits. and then that person would leave this site because of the down votes.