# How can I post my own work from an external site without it being flagged as plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I had written an article on another site which I felt was relevant to a question here, so I decided to re-post it as an answer.  However, it ended up flagged and deleted as [plagiarism](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/302/22).

Obviously the charge of plagiarism is unfounded in this case since I had written the original and it remains entirely my own work.  What recourse is available to me, and how can I prevent this from happening again in the future?

Answer (score 2):

In cases where text is unattributed yet clearly copied from a third-party site, classifying it as plagiarism is a fairly easy mistake to make.  This is especially the case with the Internet, where even when users don't post anonymously, actually *proving* their identity is often unfeasible.

The best preventative is as simple as it is effective: Attribute it anyway, just attribute it to *yourself*.  Simply come out up front about the fact that it was originally posted on a third-party website, you felt it was relevant to the answer, and summarize/quote/rework it to fit the actual question asked, just as you would any other source.

And if the only problem with your deleted post *was* a mistaken flag of plagiarism, the post can simply be edited to add the appropriate self-attribution and be flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: The OP's post is still deleted though. Can't we undelete it since he says he is the original author?

Comment: @muslim1 To my eye, that post has *significant* problems beyond the alleged plagiarism, not the least of which is the fact that it's more concerned with proving 'Aql as a jurisprudent source than it is with actually answering the question.

Comment: @goldPsedudo apart from the last paragraph, the answer is pretty relevant and to the point. If you look at the other two answers that are vid of any information but are not deleted. Why delete this answer when it has +4 up votes.

Comment: @muslim1 If you want to argue that it deserves to be undeleted, feel free to open a new meta discussion.  Just because it was explicitly (and mistakenly) deleted for plagiarism (which is the topic of *this* meta discussion) doesn't mean it's free from other delete-worthy problems.