# Need explanation from GoldPsedo about removal of an answer

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, specific-post

Here is the question, where i have provided answer of my own word, with set of 2 hadith. And my answer was deleted by biased moderator Goldpseudo.i need its explanation that how it was plagiarism. And where are the rules and who makes the rules of answers

[Witr salat with isha and tahajud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23346/witr-salat-with-isha-and-tahajud/23351?noredirect=1#comment39922_23351)

Answer (score 8):

The answer was plagiarised from [here](http://www.123muslim.com/islamic-articles/1824-witr-prayer.html) or some place else, doesn't matter as long as it was copied. It was plagiarism because the source wasn't stated. Even if it was, it is a established policy of this site that copy-paste answer are not acceptable. We aint creating a content farm out here.

Sources:

1. [What to do about plagiarism?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/3487)
2. [The copy-paste issue, revisited](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/3487)