# My answer was deleted for supposed "Plagiarism"?

Tags: support, plagiarism, sources

My answer (https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24323/is-it-allowed-to-wish-happy-mothers-day-in-islam):

> It is not permissible to greet and/or congratulate Kuffar on their holidays, an example is Christmas or New Year. We are not allowed to respond to them when they greet us on those occasions When Sheikh Ibn Uthaymeen was asked about whether we can greet the Kuffar on these occasions or attend their celebrations, he replied "Greeting the kuffar on the occasion of Christmas or any of their other religious holidays is haram according to scholarly consensus". In Ibn al-Qayyim's book, 'Ahkaam Ahl al-Dhhimma. He states:
>
> "Congratulating the kuffaar on the rituals that belong only to them is haraam by consensus, as is congratulating them on their festivals and fasts by saying ‘A happy festival to you’ or ‘May you enjoy your festival,’ and so on. If the one who says this has been saved from kufr, it is still forbidden. It is like congratulating someone for prostrating to the cross, or even worse than that. It is as great a sin as congratulating someone for drinking wine, or murdering someone, or having illicit sexual relations, and so on. Many of those who have no respect for their religion fall into this error; they do not realize the offensiveness of their actions. Whoever congratulates a person for his disobedience or bid’ah or kufr exposes himself to the wrath and anger of Allaah."
>   A hadith narrated by Abdullah ibn Umar states:
>
> "The Prophet (ﷺ) said: He who copies any people is one of them."
>   Reference: Sunan Abu Dawud 4031
>
> This may suggest that celebrating and greeting the Kuffar on their occasions is imitation which would imply that you are of one of them, and to be a Kuffar is haram, therefore it would be haram to "Wish a Happy Mother's day".
>
> I have given you evidence, now you decide on whether it wishing one a "Happy Mother's day" is halal or not.
>
> Read the full source here: http://islamqa.info/en/69811 Although, be wary, they may not have correct sources. (It is why I did not include all of the information, I just summarized parts which I found to be legit)

I do disagree with Bleeding Fingers♦ claiming my answer was plagiarism, rather I researched the internet for information (from various sites), and wrote a short meaningful answer as was requested by the OP. If what I *said* was plagiarism , then answering questions based on Madhabs would also be plagiarism or any sort of research would also be plagiarism. Sure, I used similar wording to that of the article in which I actually took care to reference, however, I don't believe my answer and that article are one in the same. Again, he asked for a short meaningful answer, and so I used legitimate resources to do so.

Am I completely wrong in this particular case?

Answer (score 2):

Answers primarily containing third-party text too are not welcome here. (sources: [What to do about plagiarism?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/3487) and [The copy-paste issue, revisited](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/3487)).

The reason it was deleted was because the first part was passed off as if it was your own, and the source I found it on wasn't the one you had attributed. Please properly quote what you take from elsewhere, and keep what you quote to the point unless entirely necessary.

Improperly quoting *can* risk your post to get deleted for plagiarism and excessive copy-paste can do that too. So it is *your* responsibility to quote and attribute the source in a proper manner.

Comment: I clearly mentioned "Read the full source here: http://islamqa.info/en/69811 Although, be wary, they may not have correct sources. (It is why I did not include all of the information, I just summarized parts which I found to be legit)". And if you look in the comments on the OP, I also mentioned it there.

Comment: "and the source I found it on wasn't the one you had attributed", I do not understand this, I stated a primary source that I used to conduct my research and to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit :) Although, just to note, I did not copy the first paragraph, I summarized the key points throughout the article. If you consider that plagiarism, then that is fine by me.

Comment: Since the sources didn't match and the text wasn't quoted it gave the impression of plagiarism.