# Review the deleted question

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, deleted-answer

why you delete [it](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24641/why-takfiris-mostly-kill-muslim-poeple-especially-shias)
not all of the question is copy paste .I can edit some paragraph no problem but its a clear answer for the question

Answer (score 3):

Part of the answer, which supposedly answered the question, was plagiarised. And on this site plagiarism and large copy-paste answers are unacceptable and subject to deletion. Answers should primarily be the authors own words. Hence the answer was deleted.

Texts quoted from elsewhere should be blockquoted and properly attributed.

Sources:

- [What to do about plagiarism?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/302/3487)
- [The copy-paste issue, revisited](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/3487)

Comment: okay ill post my question again with an edit

Comment: I made an edit on the deleted question .. can you still view it ?

Comment: Yes I can. You can repost the answer or edit the current answer and flag for undeletion. But in both case make sure it does not have plagiarised content or it will again be removed or the flag will be declined.

Comment: I edit it on current answet and I am not able to flad for undeletion because a moderator delete it , and I want you to check my edit if it is ok

Comment: You click on flag and then choose *"in need of moderator intervention"*. And no it's not, the reason of deletion still present.