# We just hit 87% answered!

Tags: discussion, questions

#### Hitting 87% answered

We started at [80% answered](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2959/17163), then we hit [84% answered](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3077/17163), and we just now hit **87% answered**!!   (After rounding.)  From [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam):

[image]

[Jon Ericson ♦](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1700/17163) previously mentioned that having 17% unanswered questions was holding us back from graduating.  (See [Are items from Jon Ericson's list from Jan 2016 still holding us back?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3084/17163))

#### A pat on the back

I feel like the community is really starting to gel.  We're generating meaningful content day after day, and it's not just one knowledgeable user: lots of people are chipping in!  It's an amazing effort!!  Bear in mind that we get 16,000+ people visiting the site per day: people are seeing this.

About a year ago, I showed this site to a friend of mine, and he advised me to stay away from it and be very careful with what I learned here.  A few weeks ago, I did the same thing with another friend, and I was amazed at how positive he was about the site.

When I joined, it was mostly goldPseudo diamond-hammer closing questions (and getting [blamed for everything wrong with the site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1859/17163)).  At this time, it appeared that without goldPseudo, the site would easily fold.  We are now far more able to self-moderate.  Nowadays, we don't need diamond moderators to hold our hands all the time---we've got this: [A sign of becoming a mature site: questions are being closed without diamond moderator intervention](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2937/17163)

Currently I feel that goldPseudo could turn around and say *I want to become an astronaut*, and the community could reply *that's cool, we got this; enjoy space*.

It feels like a different site to a few years ago.  (See: [Is this site being abandoned and neglected?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1797/17163) from 1 year, 6 months ago)

#### The road to 90% answered

We got to 87% relatively easily: many questions were resolved by closing, triggering auto-delete, and upvoting answers to unanswered questions.  ***To get to 90% answered we're probably going to need to answer maybe 200 to 300 unanswered questions.***

This is why I made this post: [List of 27 "unanswered" questions which are answered in the comments (Mar 2018)](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3303/17163)  I feel like these questions can be easily answered.

The math:

- The current number of [questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions) is `8377`.  We divide by ten to obtain `837`.  This is the 10% unanswered level.
- We're currently have `1127` [unanswered questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/unanswered).
- So we need to answer `1127 - 837 = 290` questions.

We're not going to need to do exactly this: some will be closed/deleted, and it looks like we're answering incoming questions at a rate of 90%+.

#### Questions per day

We're also close to hitting 10 questions per day (*When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation* [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)).

[image]

Here's the number of weekly questions (the orange line is the target):

[image]

I mentioned this here [Getting closer to the 10 questions per day mark!](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3003/17163), but it looks like that was prompted by a blip in the number of questions.

> Of note, the "questions per day" metric is closely tied to the "answered" metric: When people see that existing questions are actually getting answers, especially good answers, they're more likely to ask more questions.  – [goldPseudo ♦](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/the-increasing-popularity-of-islam-se/2953#comment6203_2953)