# Are people on this site fully qualified to answer questions here?

Tags: discussion

I'm concerned that people are throwing around fatawa without knowledge. FOR ALLAH to legislate what is haram and halal is part of Tawheed. It falls in all parts of Tawheed. Tawheedun Uloohiyah (worship), Tawheedun (Rubbobiyah) and Tawheedun Asma wa siffat (names and qualities).

So can the maker of this site please ensure that not fulan answers but students of knowledge or shuyookh (Sheikhs).

Jazakamullah khair.

Comment: In an ostensibly anonymous forum for Q&As, asking fatwa questions is off-topic. Moreover, there are no means that one may qualify or verify who a student of knowledge is. This is not to impune your argument about fatwa questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anybody can answer here, and it is the responsibility of the community to ensure that poor answers are downvoted and expert answers are upvoted. This is not something that the makers of the site are qualified to judge: The expertise of the answers is directly reflected by the expertise of the community, so it is important to ensure that you the community are attracting *expert* users who are qualified to judge and answer the sorts of questions you want.

Otherwise, all answers here should be taken with a grain of salt, and all questions should be written under the assumption that literally *anybody* can answer. If a certain level of expertise is required in an answer it is incumbent on the questioner to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

From the [on-topic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page

> It is also important to note that this is not a fatwa site. While questions on the legality of actions (from an Islamic perspective) are welcome, **answers may be posted by anybody regardless of training or expertise. It is important to judge the evidences provided by each answer to the best of your own abilities, and accept such answers at your own risk.**

In principle, anyone can answer.  In practice, there are mechanisms so that low-quality answers are minimized, weeded out, and drop to the bottom:

- **Downvoting**.  See [Why is voting important?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)
- **Comments**.  [When should I comment?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)  Request clarification; Leave constructive criticism; ...
- **Flagging**.  Suitable for "not an answer" answers, [plagiarism](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/17163), etc.  See the [flag posts](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) help page.
- **Deletion**.  By both the community, and diamond moderators.  See: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)  (Downvoted answers are also deleted when an account is deleted; see [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user/88996#88996).)

There are also others mechanisms, such as [protecting questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), [answering limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900), [answer bans](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans), and [review queues](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review).

The reputation system gives a coarse indication of how reliable a user is.  A user with 10000+ reputation points has attracted a large number of upvotes, and thus other users have thought their contributions are worthwhile.  On the other hand, a user with <200 reputation has not received as much positive feedback.

Answer (score -3):

What exactly is the point of this site if only certain individuals declared experts by proprietary institutions are allowed to answer? God in the Quran has made it clear that He is the teacher of His revealed Deen in the Quran.

```
He taught the Quran.(Quran 55:02)
```

And the primary manner in which this understanding is to be gained is through the use of God given powers of observation, logic and rational thought. Besides,
the verses of the Quran are already in an explained state and the responsibility of explaining them is also taken up by God Himself.

```
Alif Lam Ra. This is a Book with Divine Writ,its Verses explained in detail from the one
 All-Wise, All-Aware.: Quran 11.01

Then indeed, upon Us (is) its explanation: Quran 75:19
```

In the absence of sufficient number of Mutawatir Ahadith, (estimates range from 10 to 300) the only true and sufficient source of our Deen is the Quran.

Hence, once the understanding is gained with the direct help of God, it is perfectly normal for this understanding to be shared.

What you are proposing is more suited for Fatwa dot com and Islam Q and A type of sites.